# Custom Paths in Web Browser Control for PDFs in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba, ms-access-2013

I want to display PDF files for each separate record on my form in Access. The form is populated from a combo box's result (select a key field from combo box), and form gets populated with a large amount of info from a query.

For each unique value in the underlying table, there is a pdf file related to it. I want to use the web browser control to define the file path for each unique key. For example,

> S:\FolderPath\xyz\keyvalue.pdf"

where `keyvalue.pdf` is literally the contents of a text box on the form that has the text field source for that record followed by a '.pdf' so if my key is 1, it will be `1.pdf`, if it is A-22ds, the file will be `A-22ds.pdf`.

Comment: Do you have a problem creating the path, or populating the web browser control with it? These sound like very separate issues.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, I am having trouble determining where to specify the path. Because it will depend on which record is open on the form, the path cannot be constant. I need to define it in a way that allows the key variable to be part of the path string.

Comment: That doesn't narrow it down a lot. Can you construct the string (e.g. create a function that returns it) or not?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, 

This is what I have so far:
   `Dim path As String  
    Dim filename As String    path = "S:\MDM\MIRS\SCOPE-MP\"


    filename = Me.cboPSENumber.Value + "_MP.pdf"


    'Final path should be path + filename `

Comment: And does that return the desired filename?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I get the correct filename if i just print it in a message box to test it, but how do I get the browser control to display the file under that pathname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a form with a web browser control called MyWebbrowserControl, and you want to get the PDF in there:

```
Public Sub LoadPDF(MyPdfLocation As String)
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim strHTML As String
    strHTML = "<html><head><title>My PDF</title></head><body>" & _
    "<embed style=""width:100%;height:100%;"" src=""" & Application.HtmlEncode(MyPdfLocation) & """ type=""application/pdf""></embed></body></html>"
    Set wb = MyWebbrowserControl.Object
    With wb
        .Navigate2 "about:blank"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4 '=READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            'This is an inefficient way to wait, but loading a blank page should only take a couple of milliseconds
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.Open
        .Document.Write strHTML 
        .Document.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

(I'm using very generic HTML, it might benefit from some tweaking).

Them call it on `Form_Current`, for example:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim path As String 
    Dim filename As String 
    path = "S:\MDM\MIRS\SCOPE-MP\" 
    filename = Me.cboPSENumber.Value + "_MP.pdf" 'Final path should be path + filename 
    Me.LoadPDF path & filename
End Sub
```